# Why does submitting a Spark application to Mesos fail with "Could not parse Master URL: 'mesos://localhost:5050'"?

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I'm getting the following exception when I'm trying to submit a Spark application to a Mesos cluster:

> 17/01/31 17:04:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   17/01/31 17:04:22 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'mesos://localhost:5050' at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2550) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:501)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably used a wrong command to build Spark, e.g., missing `-Pmesos`. You should build it using `./build/mvn -Pmesos -DskipTests clean package` since Spark 2.1.0.

Comment: Curious where this `-Pmesos` option is documented at? I haven't been able to find any other reference to it anywhere.

Comment: See http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/building-spark.html#building-with-mesos-support